# Wordpress admin can able to login but wp-admin and other admin pages are not opening

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, vps

My WordPress website is hosted on GoDaddy VPS. Can able to make successful login to the `wp-login` page but when its redirect to the wp-admin page and I am getting  **HTTP 500 ERROR** on all admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems some PHP fatal error happens on the admin page. Please try by deactivating all plugins one by one via FTP (You can rename each plugin folder name, it will deactivate the plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the timely reply. Even after rename of plugins through FTP and still facing the same issue!

Comment: Make sure all plugins are deactivated. if the issue persists try by deactivating theme.

Comment: If you have done some changes on function.php, please clear all.

Comment: I have all the above solutions of yours but still its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

This is normally caused by .htaccess issues. Why not try to delete the .htaccess. And trying. If that doesn't help, hopefully this link might be useful https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/.
Before trying the "Re-uploading Core Files" comment on the progress. Will let you know others ways that might be workout.